# will pre-installed windows 8 on laptop boot if I disable secure boot in BIOS?

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios

I have laptop with 2 HDD (Toshiba P870) and Windows 8 preinstalled on the first drive.
Secure boot is enabled.
When I install Linux (Ubuntu 12.04.2) on second drive it can't boot because of authentication problem. 
if I disable secure boot in bios - will I still be able to boot Windows 8?

Comment: Why don't you try it? If anything goes wrong, you should be able to enable it back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows 8 will still boot. I also did this on my `Dell Inspiron 15R SE`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 boots normally no matter you disable or enable the Secure Boot option. It only fails to boot after changing the BIOS mode from UEFI to Legacy (without CSM support).